# AOSP ICS build error

Tags: android, c++, ubuntu, android-source

I'm trying to compile ICS for galaxy 5 in a Virtual machine running Linux ubuntu 11.10 64-bit,

All is right configured(i think) but when I use :

```
make clean && mka bacon -j1
```

I got these errors:

```
target thumb C++: libmedia <= frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:408:1: warning: "CHECK_INTERFACE" redefined
In file included from frameworks/base/include/binder/IMemory.h:26,
                 from frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:21:
frameworks/base/include/binder/IInterface.h:107:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp: In member function 'virtual android::status_t android::BnOMX::onTransact(uint32_t, const android::Parcel&, android::Parcel*, uint32_t)':
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:419: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:427: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:450: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:470: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:481: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:499: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:541: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:555: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:569: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:584: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:604: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:625: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:639: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:661: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:683: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:695: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:706: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:725: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp: In member function 'virtual android::status_t android::BnOMXObserver::onTransact(uint32_t, const android::Parcel&, android::Parcel*, uint32_t)':
frameworks/base/media/libmedia/IOMX.cpp:771: error: call of overloaded 'enforceInterface(const android::String16&)' is ambiguous
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:77: note: candidates are: bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&, android::IPCThreadState*) const
frameworks/base/include/binder/Parcel.h:80: note:                 bool android::Parcel::enforceInterface(const android::String16&) const
make: *** [out/target/product/galaxy5/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmedia_intermediates/IOMX.o] Error 1
```

Anyone know how to solve it?

Or even skip it?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove everything in this directory: `out/target/product/galaxy5/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libmedia_intermediates`, then run the command again, without `make clean`.